# How to Refresh Web Service Value

Tags: development, infopath, web-services

I have an InfoPath 2010 form that is pulling data from a web service.

For example, I have a text box, a button, and a drop down list. The button submits the text box value to the web service. The drop down list has the values of the queried results from the web service.

So what I'm trying to do is when the user places a different value in the text box and then clicks the button, the drop down list is updated with the new values.

I can not get the actions to repost and refresh the drop down list. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what rjcup3 said.  Easiest way to do this is to add a rule that sets your web server parm again then another rule that queries data and select your web service as the data source.  This would be a no code solution.

Once the data is queried again, if your ddl is bound to the web service datafield it will automatically refresh.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is call the web service again with the updated user input from the button's click handler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa947848.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-buttons-HA101783359.aspx?CTT=1#_Toc275279770

Comment: And then update the UI...